# How to deal with TS errors about required fields that are only about to be filled?

Tags: typescript

Pretty standard use case would be to create an empty object and fill it with the necessary data. At the end of the filling process, the object is going to contain all of its required properties, but when it gets created it has none and thus TypeScript wont allow me to type this new object with the correct type.

Example:

```js
interface ISomeType {
  x: string;
  y: string;
}

function buildObj(): ISomeType {
  const obj: ISomeType = {}; // TS Error: {} doesn't include x and y
  obj.x = foo();
  obj.y = bar(); // At the end of the filling process, the object is correct

  return obj;
}
```

How do I deal with this issue? How do I make TypeScript understand that this new object is supposed to be of the specified type, it just doesn't have the required properties yet and will have them at the end?

If I mark `obj` with the type `Partial<ISomeType>` then I can't mark the function return type with `ISomeType` which is my intention.

Comment: Why do you split object creation and properties assignment? `const obj: ISomeType = { x: foo(), y: bar() };`

Comment: This is obviously a simplified example. Usually there are conditions and loops involved in the building process.

Comment: Sure, this means these parts should be extracted to methods or their results should be put into variables. You can't define empty object and then expect from complier to somehow check that all required properties are filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would construct parts first and just return object literal:

```
function buildObj(): ISomeType {
    const x = foo(); // const x: ISomeType['x'] = foo();
    const y = bar();
    return {
        x,
        y
    };
}
```

There is no reason to create the object before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function buildObj(): ISomeType {
  const obj: Partial<ISomeType> = {}; // TS Error: {} doesn't include x and y
  obj.x = foo();
  obj.y = bar(); // At the end of the filling process, the object is correct

  return obj as ISomeType;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't forcefully typing it as `ISomeType` at the end beat the point of typing it in the first place?

Comment: Yes and no. Partial is exposed only within the function and you as a function owner ensure it cannot go wrong when you build your objects this way. The world does need to know what dirty things you do inside your function. So the function caller still knows they get a ISomeType.

Comment: Naturally the issue raises when object gets complex, more properties are added and if you are not maintaining `buildObj` yourself, then errors start to get slip through. But this is not usually the problem if there is only one way to construct instances.

Comment: Typescript isn't there only to help others use your code, it's there to help you as well. You can really easily forget to build one property of the object and then cast it wrong. Definitely DON'T do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also populate the object from the start with values of the fields

```
function buildObj(): ISomeType {
 const obj: ISomeType = {
   obj.x = foo();
   obj.y = bar();
 }

 return obj;
}
```

You should be able to gather all of the information you need before constructing the object and then create it. This will ensure type safety.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't DO**

[Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). Even though it will allow you to bypass the error. It will cause you a lot of problem in a long run. Because it practically says that this object is a valid object of this particular type, whereas its not.

```
<ISomeType>{}
```

**DO**

[Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html). They will allow you to modify source object according to your needs.

[Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt)

> Constructs a type with all properties of T set to optional. This utility will return a type that represents all subsets of a given type.

```
interface ISomeType {
  x: string;
  y: string;
}

const someType:Partial<ISomeType> = {};

// Behind the scene it does following:
interface ISomeType {
  x?: string;
  y?: string;
}
```

[Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk)

> Constructs a type by picking the set of properties K from T

```
const someType:Pick<ISomeType, 'x'> = {
  x: 0
};
```

Furthermore. I'd recommend you to skim through [TypeScript Coding Guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines). In TypesScript interfaces shall not be prefixed with I, like in C#.

Comment: `In TypesScript interfaces shall not be prefixed with I, like in C#.` Did you read the part in font size 32, font weight 600, all CAPS, where it said "STOP READING IMMEDIATELY, THIS PAGE PROBABLY DOES NOT PERTAIN TO YOU, This is NOT a prescriptive guideline for the TypeScript community"?

Comment: Yes @ritaj, but in C# Interfaces define contracts and classes implements them whereas in TS they are not... Thats a major difference.

Comment: And in TS interfaces have multiple purposes, one of which is the same as in C#, and the other is to define contracts for objects that have to implement them.